# Word 2010: Ignoring or moving inconsequential words like "the" when sorting

Tags: regex, sorting, ms-word

I have a table that I want to sort, but some of the items I'll be sorting by begin with "The". My first thought was to do a Find and Replace to move "the" to the end of that cell's contents, do a sort, and then move it back. I tried a basic `The (?)*` in the Find What and then `\1, The` in the Replace With, thinking that ? would match any character and * would match any number of those any characters. I have tried other variations with no success. The expression seems to be defaulting to non-greedy, only matching the first letter of the following word. I can force it to match more by using, say, the end of word marker >, and sure enough, then it starts matching the entire next word. But I want the rest of the cell's contents after the "The", not just one word. There is no way to create a regular expression to match all the list items, as they are not uniform in their structure.

So, any way to make Find and Replace greedy, or is there an equivalent to ^ and $ (or another way to match beginning and end of table cell) that I'm just not finding? Or perhaps 2010's sort mechanism is now more sophisticated and can deal with inconsequential words like "the"?

NOTE: I'd prefer to stay away from VBA - this was just supposed to be a quick process. I know nothing of the language and don't care to learn at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, the `.` (period) symbol means 'any character' so give that a try. (The `?` symbol means 'match one or zero'.)

Also, you want the `*` (match any number) symbol inside the parentheses, otherwise the parenthetic clause may only match the first character it finds after "The ".

So try:

```
^The (.*)$
```